# How to use internal #[derive(Debug)] in std::fmt::Debug

Tags: rust

I want to customize the output of a `struct` called `FooOut` but I don't want to change the debug output of the internal field `FooIn` which is inside `FooOut`. Consider the Rust [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6aa83533bbe87102a18dd352f4651a9d):

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct FooOut {
    num1: u32,
    num2: u32,
    obj: FooIn,
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct FooIn {
    bval: bool,
    list: Vec<u32>,
}

impl std::fmt::Debug for FooOut {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "FooOut {{ sum: {}, num1: {}, num2: {}, obj: {} }}",
                   self.num1 + self.num2,
                   self.num1,
                   self.num2,
                   self.obj)  // self.obj is not working without implementing it too
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am trying to customize the debug output of `FooOut` (by adding `sum`), but I don't want to customize/reimplement the debug output of `FooIn`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: If you want to use `FooIn`'s debugging output, then you should use `... obj: {:?}` placeholder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of manually constructing the debug string yourself, I recommend that you use [`Formatter::debug_struct`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.debug_struct) (or one of its sibling functions) instead:

```rust
impl std::fmt::Debug for FooOut {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("FooOut")
            .field("sum", &(self.num1 + self.num2))
            .field("num1", &self.num1)
            .field("num2", &self.num2)
            .field("obj", &self.obj)
            .finish()
    }
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d9c6a01b8c3858a9874584722d8a9371)

This is what `#[derive(Debug)]` is using to build the default debug string for an object. This also has the added advantage that you get both the compact debug string with `{:?}` and the alternative, expanded debug string with `{:#?}`.

Comment: Of course can be combined with both explicit `write!`s and explicit calls to the `Debug::fmt` methods of the members, which will then inherit the `alternate()` flag of the formatter.

Answer (score 2):

( Adding Alex Larionov's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623087/how-to-use-internal-derivedebug-in-stdfmtdebug#comment112506119_63623087) as the answer. )

Instead of using `{}` for `FooIn`, I need to use `{:?}` to use the debug output of `FooIn`

```
impl std::fmt::Debug for FooOut {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "FooOut {{ sum: {}, num1: {}, num2: {}, obj: {:?} }}",
                   self.num1 + self.num2,
                   self.num1,
                   self.num2,
                   self.obj)
    }
}
```